# Xamarin Resource Dictionary with Dynamic Resource not updating

Tags: wpf, xaml, xamarin

I created 2 themes for my Xamarin app (Xamarin Forms v3.5). I merge the first one when app starts like so (in App.xaml):

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/DarkResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I change the theme in App.xaml.cs like so:

```
Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
        var resourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
        resourceDictionary.SetAndLoadSource(uri, uri.ToString(), this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly, null);
        resourceDictionary.Source = uri;
        Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resourceDictionary);
```

This works 100%, but the styles in the resource dictionaries are not applied until I re-open a form even though I use Dynamic Resource like so:

```
<Grid Style="{DynamicResource DisplayBackground}">
```

Im sure Im overlooking something small. Any ideas? Thanks a bunch

Comment: Use Xamarin.Forms dynamic resources. Below is a link to the Xamarin documentation:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/dynamic/

Comment: So, do you have any idea why it's not updating?

Comment: I posted a ticket in the Xamarin.Forms GitHub project: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6795